# How to change wsdl location file inside service

Tags: java, wsdl

I have a preliminary MyService generated with the wsimport gradle task with provided wsdl location path file:/D:/someLocationWherePlacedMyWSDl.interface.v2.wsdl

```
public class MyService
    extends Service
{

    private final static URL MyService_WSDL_LOCATION;
    private final static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(com.google.services.MyService.class.getName());

    static {
        URL url = null;
        try {
            URL baseUrl;
            baseUrl = com.google.services.MyService.class.getResource(".");
            url = new URL(baseUrl, "file:/D:/someLocationWherePlacedMyWSDl.interface.v2.wsdl");
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            logger.warning("Failed to create URL for the wsdl Location: 'file:/D:/someLocationWherePlacedMyWSDl.interface.v2.wsdl', retrying as a local file");
            logger.warning(e.getMessage());
        }
        MyService_WSDL_LOCATION = url;
    }
}
```

How can I change it? It happens because the file was generated in one environment and then the artifact (war) was moved to another server.

Any thoughts?

---

Yes, I get it.  Locally everything works perfectly. But this file located inside war file and when Jenkins trying to get this file /var/distributives/myservice/tomcat-base/wsdl/someLocationWherePlacedMyWSDl.interface.v2.wsdl I get exception (No such file or directory). It looks like it could not see files inside war file. Any thoughts how can I handle this?

Answer (score 0):

Use the constructor of your service class, `MyService`, to pass the `wsdlLocation`.

```
String WSDL_LOCATION = "http://server:port/localtionWSDL.interface.v2.wsdl";

try {
    final URL url = new URL(WSDL_LOCATION);
    final QName serviceName = new QName("http://mynamespace/", "MyService");
    final MyService service = new MyService(url, serviceName);
    port = service.getMyServicePort();

    // Call some operation of WebService

} catch (final Exception e) {
    // Handle the exception
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem with relative path. Here is the solution

`@Value("classpath:com//google//resources//wsdl//myservice.interface.v2.wsdl")
    public void setWsdlLocation(final Resource wsdlLocation)
    {
        m_wsdlLocation = wsdlLocation;
    }`